# Wine -stable-i386 error

Tags: wine

I'm having trouble installing wine from terminal. I used `sudo apt-get install wine-stable` and `sudo apt-get install wine-stable-i386` and received this error.

```
sudo apt-get install wine-stable-i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine-stable-i386:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.28) but 2.27-3ubuntu1 is to be installed
                         Recommends: libcapi20-3:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libcups2:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libglu1-mesa:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
                                     libglu1:i386
                         Recommends: libgsm1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libkrb5-3:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libodbc1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libosmesa6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libsane:i386 or
                                     libsane1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libv4l-0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libxcomposite1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libxslt1.1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Any recommendations?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)